# What is the solution to the equation below?

Tags: complex-numbers

Solve the equation below.

$$x^2+\frac{81x^2}{(9+x)^2}=40$$

I couldn't solve it after trying many time.

Comment: differential equations?

Comment: First you clear out the denominator, giving you a quartic polynomial equation. In principle it can be factored analytically... in practice, unless there's an obvious factorization, you use a numerical method to find the roots.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20x%5E2%2b%2881x%5E2%29/%289%2bx%29%5E2%20=40) is the answer computed in Wolfram|Alpha. Note that there is a feature on this site, called "Step-by-step solution," that allows you to see precisely how they arrived at the answer.

Comment: Please try to describe as much here as possible in order to make the answer self-contained. Links are fine as support, but they can go stale and then an answer which is nothing more than a link loses its value.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying both sides by $(x+9)^2$ yields
$$(x^2+18x+162)x^2=40(x^2+18x+81)$$
which is equivalent to
$$x^4+18x^3+122x^2-720x-3240=0$$
Factorization gives
$$x^4+18x^3+122x^2-720x-3240=(x^2+20x+180)(x^2-2x-18)$$
Which has roots, given by the quadratic formula,
$$1+\sqrt{19},1-\sqrt{19},-10+i\sqrt{80},-10-i\sqrt{80}$$